# Writing divs with PHP if/else statements

Tags: php, if-statement

This is coming from a wordpress site I'm working on, but isn't a WP-specific question.

I have an if/else PHP statement that checks whether the user is looking at my site's home page or not. If they are looking at the home page, I want the code to do nothing. If they AREN'T, I want it to display the page title in a  config.

The code I currently have is:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>
    <?php
    if ( is_front_page()){
        echo ' ';
    }
    elseif (is_home()) {
        if (get_option('page_for_posts', true)) {
          echo get_the_title(get_option('page_for_posts', true));
        } else {
          _e('Latest Posts', 'roots');
        }
      } elseif (is_archive()) {
        $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
        if ($term) {
          echo $term->name;
        } elseif (is_post_type_archive()) {
          echo get_queried_object()->labels->name;
        } elseif (is_day()) {
          printf(__('Daily Archives: %s', 'roots'), get_the_date());
        } elseif (is_month()) {
          printf(__('Monthly Archives: %s', 'roots'), get_the_date('F Y'));
        } elseif (is_year()) {
          printf(__('Yearly Archives: %s', 'roots'), get_the_date('Y'));
        } elseif (is_author()) {
          global $post;
          $author_id = $post->post_author;
          printf(__('Author Archives: %s', 'roots'), get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id));
        } else {
          single_cat_title();
        }
      } elseif (is_search()) {
        printf(__('Search Results for %s', 'roots'), get_search_query());
      } elseif (is_404()) {
        _e('File Not Found', 'roots');
      } else {
        the_title();
      }
    ?>
  </h1>
</div>
```

I know the `echo ' ';` is probably way off, but I'm an absolute php beginner! At present this creates an empty `<div>` and `<h4>` tag, but I'd rather clean it up and create nothing at all on the home page.

How can I best modify the code above to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your code around. If you don't want the leading `<div><h1>` be printed on the front page, then move the `if` check before that. Add an `else` where you then print the `<div><h1>`, the big if/else code blob, and the closing `</div>`, etc.

Also read up on [switching in and out of PHPs code and html mode](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).
Albeit, it's probably best explained by just showing:

```
<?php
    if ( is_front_page()){
        echo ' ';
    }
    else {
?>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>
    <?php

    if (is_home()) {
        if (get_option('page_for_posts', true)) {
          echo get_the_title(get_option('page_for_posts', true));

       /*

           ...

       */

      } else {
        the_title();
      }
    ?>
  </h1>
</div>
<?php
     }
?>
```

The only interesting thing here is that you enclose the html+code blob between the `else`s opening `{` and closing `}` curly brace.

Comment: Why not remove the `else` and use `if (!is_front_page()){`? OP just wants nothing on that page, so echoing a space is unnecessary.

Comment: OP seems confused enough, so I dropped the negation, also kept the redundant empty `echo` in. It's just showcasing the structure.

Comment: Haha thanks for this guys. I actually thought of doing something like this but didn't think you could just chuck html inside a PHP if/else statement. `if (!is_front_page()){` seems simple enough so I'll use that. Cheers guys!

Answer (score 0):

Put your echos into a variable instead of printing them, then after your if statements do

echo ($var =='') ? '' : ''.$var.'';

Html tags between the last 2 sets of single quotes